# Hello World Tutorial - Using the Debug Perspective

Tags: android, installation, debugging

I've just started going through the tutorials but seem to be having some trouble with the following portion:

"Run > Debug History > Hello, Android from the menu to enter debug mode. Your app will restart in the emulator, but this time it will suspend when it reaches the breakpoint you set. You can then step through the code in Eclipse's Debug Perspective, just as you would for any other application."

when I follow these instructions I see a list of warnings like this...

[2010-11-24 15:39:43 - ddms]Can't bind to local 8617 for debugger

and finally this...

[2010-11-24 16:08:25 - HelloAndroidWeb] Launch error: Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.

I've never used a debugger before but from reading the tutorail I expect a new window to open (the Debug Perspective), but this is not the case. Have I dont something wrong in during installation/setup.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the application running on the emulator or an attached device? If on a device, USB Debugging mode needs to be enable through the setup menu.  If in the emulator, you may have to restart it in order to reattach the debugger (ADB).

In the 'Devices' panel do you see the list of active processes running? Can you select your application and click on the 'Debug select process' icon?

Comment: I'm running the app on the emulator. How would I reattach the debugger? How do you "step through the code in Eclipse's Debug Perspective"?

Comment: In the Devices panel all the processes have a bug symbol with red circle and a line through it over the bug. If I try to click on the 'Debug select process' icon I get a pop up with "The process debug port is already in use!"

Answer (score 1):

Is debbing set to true in your manifest?

Comment: This was the tutoiral I was looking at: developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html. Dubuggable is set to true in my manifest